# How to write ± symbol in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to write this "±" symbol directly in Rmarkdwon (and not in a chunk).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the symbol directly, like you did in your question.

You can also use the HTML entity `&pm;` … but I prefer the direct way.

Comment: or $\pm$ (but it will induce a MathJax dependency ...)

Comment: Yes &pm; works thanks. When i tried to use ± directly I encouter a knit error

Comment: @Ian.T There definitely shouldn’t be an error — knitr has no issue with Unicode. If there is, you should attempt to fix this instead (e.g. ensure your file is saved with UTF-8 encoding).